# How can I add dynamic control another class in method?

Tags: c#, groupbox

I generated these buttons(sepete ekle) dynamically. This button has an click event.

I want to make : when this button clicked flowlayout panel add to groupbox control.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register your button to the click event and then, transfert the control in your flowLayoutPanel

```
    private void Init()
    {
        button.Click += Button_Click;//you button
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button) sender;

        panel.Controls.Remove(button);// your control containing the button...
        flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(button);// your flowLayoutPanel
    }
```